# Telegram Bot добавление кнопок

Tags: python, telebot, бот

```
    import telebot
from telebot import types


bot=telebot.TeleBot('TOKEN')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup=types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1=types.KeyboardButton(' Провести сделку')
    btn2=types.KeyboardButton(' Мои сделки')
    # btn3=types.KeyboardButton(' Мои сделки')
    btn3 = types.KeyboardButton(' Помощь')
    # btn7=types.KeyboardButton('♻В начало')
    markup.add(btn1,btn2,btn3)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Добро пожаловать на Funpay AutoGarant, приятных сделок '+message.from_user.first_name,reply_markup=markup)

def go():
    print('вызвана функция go')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['go'])
def menu(message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Принять', callback_data = 'yes')
    item_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text = 'Отказаться', callback_data = 'no')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Доброго времени суток, вы желаете провести сделку?')
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите TelegramID пользователя с кем хотите провести сделку, далее нажмите "Принять" или "Отказаться" ')
    markup_inline.add(item_yes, item_no)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сделайте выбор', reply_markup=markup_inline)

bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        go()

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        btn_my_site = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Передать предмет', url='https://steamcommunity.com/tradeoffer/new/?partner=73601843&token=b-x64LSH')
        markup_inline.add(btn_my_site)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Для начала отправьте на нашего трейд-бота предмет',reply_markup=markup_inline)                                                                                                                           
    elif call.data == 'no':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Ваш выбор - Отказаться')
        # bot.edit_message_text('Ваш выбор - Отказаться', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
if __name__=="__main__":

    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: `под текстом, а не в панели`, что вы тут имели ввиду? Кнопки могут быть в клавиатуре или под сообщением. Что у вас не получается?

Comment: так же не совсем ясно зачем выводить команду после нажатия на кнопку.

Comment: Чтобы при нажатии на кнопку под сообщением отправлялись новые сообщения от бота с url ссылкой снизу

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Принять', callback_data='yes')
    item_no = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Отказаться', callback_data='no')
    markup_inline.add(item_yes, item_no)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сделайте выбор', reply_markup=markup_inline)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        # bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Ваш выбор - Принять')
        bot.edit_message_text('Ваш выбор - Принять', call.message.chat.id,call.message.message_id)
    elif call.data == 'no':
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Ваш выбор - Отказаться')
        # bot.edit_message_text('Ваш выбор - Отказаться', call.message.chat.id, call.message.message_id)
```

используйте [callback_query_handler](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/inline_keyboard_example.py)

Обновление исходя из комментариев к ответу:

```
def go():
    print('вызвана функция go')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item_yes = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Принять', callback_data='yes')
    markup_inline.add(item_yes)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Сделайте выбор', reply_markup=markup_inline)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == 'yes':
        go()
```

Comment: все равно не могу понять, при нажатии на принять бот выписывает команду /accept, но она должна сама использоваться от лица юзера

Comment: скорее всего у вас для команды `/accept` описана функция. так зачем вам отправлять команду боту после нажатия кнопки если можно просто вызвать функцию?

Comment: У меня в def start есть 3 кнопки, как сделать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку выводилась функция go описаная выше

Comment: `if call.data == 'button' go(*args)`

Comment: можно немного понятней написать, в плане какого-нибудь примера

Comment: ответ обновлён.

Comment: Обновил полностью код, все равно ничего не выходит, извините уж такого бездаря как я, просто хочется научиться писать ботов.

Comment: напишите свой ник в телеграм